# Angular 7 - How to get the data out of a table?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to this forum, so if I violate any rules, please tell me!

I have following code in **app.component.html:**

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="getClient($event)">
    <td> {{ item.nr }} </td>
    <td> {{ item.content }} </td>
</tr>
```

In **app.component.ts** I get the data of an API:

```
export class AuftragslisteComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

    getItem() {
        return this.http.get("http://localhost:59643/api/lösa");
    }

    items: Object;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getItem().subscribe(data => {
            this.items = data;
            console.log(this.items);
            console.log(data);
        })
    }

    getClient() {
    }
}
```

I am try to get the item.nr by clicking a row, but I always got undefined by the alert function in the getClient function, so I deleted it.

Do anyone know how to access the correct item.nr by clicking a row?

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="getClient($event)">
```

to

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="getClient(item.nr)">
```

then in your function

```
 getClient(nr){
      alert(nr)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the item as a parameter to the function

```
(click)="getClient(item)
```

And access it from the function

```
getClient(item){
 console.log(item.nr)
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer :)! It helped me!

Answer (score 0):

template

```
(click)="getClient(item.nr)"
```

ts

```
  getClient(data){
     console.log(data);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @AnnaMarie If one of the answers solved your problem, you can accept the most useful answer!